# How do you turn a class in a class library into code in a prg?

Tags: visual-foxpro

When a class is stored in a vcx library, I am guessing it does not have the DEFINE CLASS line. If that same class is stored in a prg, it would start with DEFINE CLASS (I think). How do you take the code from a class library (the vcx) and put it in a prg? Do you just copy and paste the code from the vcx into a prg and add the DEFINE CLASS line to the top of it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Class Browser has the ability to turn a class into a VCX into code. HOWEVER, it may not be runnable code.

Open the class/form of interest in the Class Browser and click View Class Code on the tool's toolbar. That gives you a starting point.

Tamar